# Map 2 array into 1 array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 separate array but both of them have same length. How to merge them together into an array object so that it's easy to populate later?

for example

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

I expect I can have something like

```
[{'index':1,'value':'a'},{'index':2,'value':'b'}]
```

I've tried

```
    $.each(a, function(i,x){

      $.each(b, function(i,z){
        c['index'] = x;
        c['value'] = z;
      });

    });
```

But I got only `[{'index':'1','value':'a'}]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** for iterate and generate the new array

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

var res = arr1.map(function(v, i) {
  return {
    index: v,
    value: arr2[i]
  };
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you can do it with arrow function like below:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

const output = arr1.map((el, i) => ({ index: el, value: arr2[i] }));

console.log(output);
```