# I have 2 array and I want to make a single array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
const array1 = ['US', 'AG','In'] // (country code array)
const array2 = ['flagIconUS','flagIconAG','flagIconIN']
```

Result :

```
const array3 = [
  { code: "US", icon: "flagIconUS" },
  { code: "AG", icon: "flagIconAG" },
  { code: "IN", icon: "flagIconIN" },
];
```

Comment: Are the elements you wanna match have the same `index` in the two arrays? I mean in the same order?

Comment: Why use an Array when you can already make use of the ID-alike shortcode. An object seems way easier to retrieve stuff from and also easy to iterate over when needed using `Object.entries` etc.

Comment: [Map 2 array into 1 array object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33956592/14032355)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A simple `for` loop would be enough to get the expected output...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map 2 array into 1 array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956592/map-2-array-into-1-array-object)

Answer (score 3):

This is simple one-liner with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const array1 = ["US", "AG", "In"];
const array2 = ["flagIconUS", "flagIconAG", "flagIconIN"];

const result = array1.map((code, i) => ({ code, icon: array2[i] }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What happens when they have mismatching sizes?

Comment: According to OP's question and expected result. If there is a mismatch then OP would have specifically mentioned it in the question itself.

Comment: Yes, you fully answered the question. But I was wondering that it wouldn't hurt for people searching for this to elaborate on the edge cases as well.

Comment: @AntonKrug I really appreciate your concern but see we have a situation where my answer will cover it automatically. Let's say `array1` length is `2` and `array2` length is `3` then the result will be an array with 2 objects because it will iterate up to 2 and not includes the third element. Now second case is where there is `array1` length is 3 and `array2` is 2, In this case the result will show up with 3 elements and `icon` will be `undefined`, which I think is expected. So I think this is win-win situation... If I am missing something then please add up here...

Comment: @AntonKrug Please check my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816660/i-have-2-array-and-i-want-to-make-a-single-array-of-object-in-javascript/68816761#

Comment: @decpk so then that is covered as well

Comment: @Nitheesh you meant this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816761/4535300

Comment: @AntonKrug Exactly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816660/i-have-2-array-and-i-want-to-make-a-single-array-of-object-in-javascript/68816761#68816761 this one

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this:

```js
const array1 = ["US", "AG", "In"]; // (country code array)
const array2 = ["flagIconUS", "flagIconAG", "flagIconIN"];

const array3 = Array.from(
  { length: 3 },
  (_, i) => ({ code: array1[i], icon: array2[i] })
);

console.log(array3);
```

One advantage of this solution: it doesn't use one particular array as the starting point, and allows more options for cases when array lengths mismatch because you can set the length of the resulting array yourself (instead of a hard-coded `3` like I did).

Example with one superfluous item in `array1`:

```js
const array1 = ["US", "AG", "In", "superfluous"]; // (country code array)
const array2 = ["flagIconUS", "flagIconAG", "flagIconIN"];

const array3 = Array.from(
  { length: Math.min(array1.length, array2.length) },
  (_, i) => ({ code: array1[i], icon: array2[i] })
);

console.log(array3);
```

The same code works when there is one superfluous item in `array2`:

```js
const array1 = ["US", "AG", "In"]; // (country code array)
const array2 = ["flagIconUS", "flagIconAG", "flagIconIN", "superfluous"];

const array3 = Array.from(
  { length: Math.min(array1.length, array2.length) },
  (_, i) => ({ code: array1[i], icon: array2[i] })
);

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Isn't that dynamic if you use `{ length: array1.length }`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```
const array1 = ["US", "AG", "In"];
const array2 = ["flagIconUS", "flagIconAG", "flagIconIN"];

const result = array1.reduce((acc,item,index)=>{
   return acc.concat({code:item,icon:array2[index]})
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.reduce` implementation

Logic

- Create an array from 0 to 3 using `Array.from(Array(Math.max(array1.length, array2.length))`. This will create an array starting from 0 to maximum of first and second array. In our case its 3.
- Reduce this array, current value inside the reducer function will be `0, 1 and 2`. These are our required indices.
- Push to accumulator array with key from first array and icon from second array.

  ```js
  const array1 = ['US', 'AG', 'In', 'UK']; // (country code array)
  const array2 = ['flagIconUS', 'flagIconAG', 'flagIconIN'];
  const array3 = Array.from(Array(Math.max(array1.length, array2.length))
                  .keys()).reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    acc.push({
                      code: array1[curr] || '',
                      icon: array2[curr] || '',
                    })
                    return acc;
                  }, []);
  console.log(array3);
  ```

`Array.map` implementation.

Logic

- Generate an array with the same logic as mentioned  earlier.
- From this generated array run `Array.map` function.
- Return the code from `array1` and icon from `array2` with index from above array.

```js
const array1 = ['US', 'AG', 'In', 'UK'];
const array2 = ['flagIconUS', 'flagIconAG', 'flagIconIN'];
const array3 = Array.from(Array(Math.max(array1.length, array2.length)).keys()).map((index) => ({
                  code: array1[index] || '',
                  icon: array2[index] || '',
                }));
console.log(array3);
```